# What is this tree/shrub in my Florida yard?

Tags: identification, shrubs

[image]

South Florida   currently about 10 feet tall

Comment: This doesn't look like an evergreen plant - does it lose its leaves if it gets cold or in what passes for winter where you are?

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a [*Clerodendrum quadriloculare*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerodendrum_quadriloculare).

Answer (score 5):

I agree that it appears to be a Clerodendrum, perhaps a [Clerodendrum quadriloculare](http://lee.ifas.ufl.edu/Hort/GardenPubsAZ/Starburst_Clerodendrum.pdf), also called Starburst, Starburst Clerodendrum, Shooting stars, and Firecracker bush. Although it used to be classified as a [Verbena](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/plants/landscape/flowers/hgic1175.html), scientific studies now place it in the [Lamiaceae](http://www.wildflowers-and-weeds.com/Plant_Families/Lamiaceae.htm) family, which is extremely large and includes varieties of mint and other herbs.

[Starburst](http://www.floridagardener.com/pom/shootingstar.htm) can be used as a small tree or shrub, depending on your preference. The maximum height is generally 10 to 15 feet (3 to 4.5 meters). Pruning is easy, and, like many shrubs, is best done in the fall, or in the spring before budding.

It thrives best in USDA Zone 9b-11 (minimum of 25°F, -4°C), which is probably where you are in Florida. It prefers acidic soil, with a pH of 7.5 or below, especially to produce full, strong leaves.  Once established, though, it requires only moderate care to keep it healthy for many years.

Depending on the specific variety, leaves can be a solid color, like yours, or variegated. The tubular flower clusters attract hummingbirds and long-nosed butterflies, so keep an eye out for some pretty visitors!

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be *Ixora cccinea*; from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ixora_coccinea):

> **Ixora coccinea** (or **jungle geranium, flame of the woods**, and **jungle flame**) is a species of flowering plant in the *Rubiaceae* family. It is a common flowering shrub native to **Southern India** and **Sri Lanka**. It has become one of the most popular flowering shrubs in **South Florida** gardens and landscapes. Its name derives from an Indian deity.

and:

> I. coccinea is a dense, multi-branched evergreen shrub, commonly 4–6 ft (1.2–2 m) in height, but capable of reaching up to 12 ft (3.6 m) high. It has a rounded form, with a spread that may exceed its height. The glossy, leathery, oblong leaves are about 4 in (10 cm) long, with entire margins, and are carried in opposite pairs or whorled on the stems. Small tubular, scarlet flowers in dense rounded clusters 2-5 in (5–13 cm) across are produced almost all year long.

Comment: I don't think your identification is correct. Ixora has red or red pinkish flowers which look quite different. See here http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Ixora_coccinea_dwarf_red.jpg

Comment: I've edited your post to make it clear which parts were cited from elsewhere. Please see the [help center](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for information on how to reference material written by other people.

Comment: Are the leaves opposite or alternate?  I couldn't tell from your picture...

Answer (score -1):

Looks like Loropetalum chinense f. rubrum only the leaves are much larger...

[Loropetalum Chinese Fringe Flower](http://www.absolutewonder.com/loropetalum.html)[Fringe Flower](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=c168#AllImageshttp://)

Comment: If you aren't sure, it would probably have been best to have written a comment instead. Imo, it looks very dissimilar.

Comment: I wish someone could identify it - I think its fab, but I can't pin it down, frustratingly.

Comment: You really need to put more detail in this answer as to why it is the plant you think it is.  How about a picture?

Comment: The flowers look the same, the leaves look a bit too large but that could be because the plant is in shade. I'll post a picture...

Comment: It does get a bit confusing as to when to answer and when to comment.  Last time I identified something tenatively, I commented versus answering.  I was reprimanded and told to answer instead...grins!

Comment: @stormy Funny, a similar thing happened to me. When I posted photos of some leaves of a tree a couple of months ago (for identification), they said they need photos of spring leaves (and how can I possibly provide them in October?). And when I posted spring leaves in another question for another plant, they said they need autumn leaves.